# Is await Asyncio.sleep inconsistent?

Tags: python, discord.py

As the title says, is `await asynco.sleep` inconsistent? As you can see from my code below, my code is meant to wait 24hrs, then send a private message to the user. From multiple tests I have ran, the code does work if I set a short time (I have tested, 1, 2,3 min all the way up to 10 min). However, I would like it set for 24hrs.

A bit of background on how the code is ran. I use replit and use uptime robot to ping the server to make sure it stays active. The bot does function as normal 24/7 apart from this await.

So, is it that `await Asyncio.sleep` only works consistently for smaller periods of time, or is it the way I am running the code, ie through replit and uptime bot? My reason to think it could maybe be uptime bot, is I assume, if it doesnt ping, the bot turns off? Making it re-run the code? My only thought to why it can't be that is that replit's seem to stay online for 5 minute without being pinged by uptime bot. So if uptime bot does not ping, i'd assume the Replit has some leway. Also, if it did happen to turn off, it would mean I would have to manually turn it back on etc. However, as I mentioned above, the rest of the code works 24/7 so I'm really lost!

If anyone has any advice for this novice, I would greatly appreciate it!

Cheers!

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(*Discord channel id*)
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"**Welcome**: {member.name}", description=f"Thanks for joining {member.guild.name}! :partying_face:",color=0x7DF9FF) # F-Strings
    embed.add_field(name=" __**To get started:**__", value="Head over to #rules and #faq :smile:", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name=" __**How to sell and trade**__", value="you will be added to a 24hr timer, after that peroid you will have access to the sell and trade rooms", inline=True)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url) # Set the embed's thumbnail to the member's avatar image!
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    #this acts as a pause, and will count up to the time entered in secconds before executing the rest of the script 
    await asyncio.sleep(86400)
    #This bit gives members a specific role
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name="Supporter")
    await member.add_roles(role)
    #THIS BIT SENDS MEMBERS A MESSAGE ALERTING THEM OF THEIR NEW ROLE 
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(f'Hi {member.name}, Congratulations :partying_face: you have now unlocked the trade and sell rooms, please read #rules and #faq before making a post')`
```

Comment: I really wouldn't use Replit to host anything long-running. (I wouldn't use it to host anything, full stop, but that's a different thing.)

Comment: But in general, suspending a coroutine for 24 hours seems like a bad idea. You might want to consider a scheduler where you set tasks to happen at some time in the future and see if any are due or overdue, and execute them then...

Comment: ahh, so i have just started to learn python and making discord bots, most of the tuts seem to say to use replit. Have you got other suggestions i can look into? Further more, ihave you got any links to scheduler/ how i can learn more about that and try to see if i can code something like that in?

Comment: @AKX is right that setting some kind of external alarm is a better.  Alternatively, when doing long-run timers like this, it's better to have the timer run once a minute, and then use `time.time()` to see if your interval has expired yet.

Comment: @TimRoberts so im getting this right, your saying, set it so it runs at 1 minute intervals, then check the function "time.time()" if it hasnt met the time in that function it repeats? if so thats quite a interesting function. Have you got any links to useful information on time.time() as i am a novice and would need to read more into that function and how it works!

Comment: If you want repl.it to leave your instances constantly running, you need to pay them to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly accurate, replit just messes it up. You really shouldn't be using replit as a hosting service because it restarts all the time, interrupting async processes. Use a VPS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).